# Identifying related records and assigning them unique IDs / data clean-up

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I have a super messy data set. There are two columns that identify each row:

1. "id" - this is a unique identifier for each record
2. "code" - refers to a project code.  one project "code" could have several records.

Sample of the data set:

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
            id = c("C01182", "C00966", "C00130", "d34567", "c34567", "C01142",
                   "C00241", "C00232", "C01094", "C00979", "C00144"),
          code = c("13762", "13762", "13762, 13886,13850", "55653", "65247",
                   "13698", "13698", "13698", "13880", "13773, 13858, 13880", "13773, 13880")
  )
```

#### What I want is to be able to identify related records by "code"

An example of the output I would like is:

```
df1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
             id = c("C01182", "C00966", "C00130", "d34567", "c34567", "C01142",
                    "C00241", "C00232", "C01094", "C00979", "C00144"),
           code = c("13762", "13762", "13762, 13886,13850", "55653", "65247",
                    "13698", "13698", "13698", "13880", "13773, 13858, 13880", "13773, 13880"),
        new_col = c("unique_id_1", "unique_id_1", "unique_id_1", "unique_id_2",
                    "unique_id_3", "unique_id_4", "unique_id_4",
                    "unique_id_4", "unique_id_5", "unique_id_5", "unique_id_5")
   )
```

#### `new_col` is driven by `code`:

1. when there are a bunch of  codes then this record along with all the
   other records that have any of these codes are considered to be a
   unique set.
2. Also there are records with the same one `code`, these will also need to be tagged as one unique set

The unique identifier can be anything, it does not have to be as per the example.

Any ideas on this can be achieved

Comment: What if the 3rd record have '13762' and '13698'.  Then, which group it belongs to

Comment: @akrun then records 6, 7 & 8 become unique_id_1

Comment: @akrun using the `splitstackshape`  library I can split out the codes: cSplit(df, splitCols = "code", sep = ",", direction = "long")   but that's all I can think of

Comment: Any limit on count of  `,` separated values in `code` column?

Comment: @MKR there is no limit unfortunately. One had some 23 codes bunched in...this is a messy data set

Comment: Fine. Can a code be present in multiple groups?

Comment: @cephalopod How big is your data? How many different codes there are?

Comment: @cephalopod I've updated my answer with a better and much faster approach. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getGroups <- function(df) {
  require(data.table)
  setDT(df)
  l <- strsplit(df$code, ",")
  l <- lapply(l, as.integer)
  x <- rep(df$id, times = sapply(l, length))
  d <- data.table(id = x, code = unlist(l))
  D <- dcast(d, id ~ code, fun.aggregate = length, value.var = 'code')
  x <- as.matrix(D[, -1])
  g <- rep(0L, nrow(x))
  cols <- 1:ncol(x)
  i <- cols[1]
  test <- colSums(x)
  gi <- 1
  while (length(cols) > 0) {
    r = F
    while (r == F) {
      y <- rowSums(x[, i, drop = F]) > 0
      ssums <- colSums(x[y, , drop = F])
      i <- ssums > 0
      r <- all(test[i] == ssums[i])
    }
    g[y] <- gi
    gi <- gi + 1
    cols <- cols[!(cols %in% which(i))]
    i <- cols[1]
  }
  m <- D[, .(id, group = g)]
  results <- merge(df, m, by = 'id', sort = F)
  results[]
}
```

Results in:

```
getGroups(df)
#         id                code group
#  1: C01182               13762     2
#  2: C00966               13762     2
#  3: C00130  13762, 13886,13850     2
#  4: d34567               55653     4
#  5: c34567               65247     5
#  6: C01142               13698     1
#  7: C00241               13698     1
#  8: C00232               13698     1
#  9: C01094               13880     3
# 10: C00979 13773, 13858, 13880     3
# 11: C00144        13773, 13880     3
```

### Update:

For speed improvement we can replase `colSums`/`rowSums` witth `colSums2`/`rowSums2`:

```
getGroups <- function(df) {
  require(data.table)
  require(matrixStats)
  setDT(df) # convert df to data.table
  l <- strsplit(df$code, ",") # split codes to list
  l <- lapply(l, as.integer) # convert them to integers for efficiency
  x <- rep(df$id, times = sapply(l, length)) # create id vector for each code
  d <- data.table(id = x, code = unlist(l)) # combine into data.table
  # converts the data from long to wide format ( each column represents if id has particular code):
  D <- dcast(d, id ~ code, fun.aggregate = length, value.var = 'code') 
  x <- as.matrix.data.frame(D[, -1]) # convert to matrix and removes id column
  g <- rep(0L, nrow(x)) # initialise result vector
  cols <- 1:ncol(x) # creates column indices vector
  test <- colSums(x) # calculates how much id have each code / for testing if we have selected all
  gi <- 1 # first group value
  while (length(cols) > 0) {
    i <- cols[test[cols] == max(test[cols])][1] # selects code column from remaining which have largest count of id`s
    r <- F # initialise indicator if we have selected all id in group
    while (r == F) {
      if (is.integer(i) != T) i <- which(i == T) # if logical converts to integer indicies
      y <- rowSums2(x, cols = i) > 0 # get indices of ids which is in current selection
      ssums <- colSums2(x, rows = y) # for those ids get all code columns and cont how many ids have each
      i <- ssums > 0 # converts to logical
      r <- all(test[i] == ssums[i]) # if selected column sums are equal to initial col sums, then we have selected all one group ids
    }
    g[y] <- gi # give group id
    gi <- gi + 1 # increase group id
    cols <- cols[!(cols %in% which(i))] # remove cols that was in this group
  }
  m <- D[, .(id, group = g)] 
  results <- merge(df, m, by = 'id', sort = F) # merge group id to initial data
  results[]
}
```

Timings on larger data:

```
n1 <- 10000
n2 <- 10000
set.seed(20)
ll <- lapply(1:n1, function(x) sample(1:n2, sample(1:5, 1)))
df <- data.table(id = 1:n1, codes = sapply(ll, paste, collapse = ', '))

system.time(wFroups1 <- getGroupsOld(df)) # 17.96
system.time(wFroups2 <- getGroups(df)) #5.35
```

Comment: I used your second function to get the job done - it worked as expected. It would help very much if you could explain the workings of your function.

Comment: @cephalopod I have added comments in the function, but i would suggest that you go trough each step on the test data by yourself and then you should get whats happening...

Comment: worked through it, could you explain why you put the following lines in, as the function works without them: `# r <- F # initialise indicator if we have selected all id in group
        # while (r == F) {
        # if (is.integer(i) != T) i <- which(i == T) # if logical converts to integer indicies
    # r <- all(test[i] == ssums[i]) # if selected column sums are equal to initial col sums, then we have selected all one group ids
     # }`

Comment: this is my understanding of your strategy: 
# Step 1: Convert the column to be used for grouping into wide format
# Step 2: Select the column from 1 above that has the highest frequency of occurences
# Step 3: The row numbers with data can be considered one group
# Step 4: repeat from steps 2 after removing the grouped rows in step 3

Answer (score 2):

**New answer:**

```
# load 'data.table' package & convert 'df' to a data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

d1 <- df[, .(code = unlist(tstrsplit(code, ',', type.convert = TRUE))), by = id]
d2 <- d1[, dcast(.SD, id ~ code, fun = length)][, -1]

df[d1[.(code = as.integer(names(d2)), val = colSums(as.matrix(d2)))
      , on = .(code), val := i.val][, .(code = code[which.max(val)]), by = id]
   , on = .(id)
   , new_col := rleid(i.code)][]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df
>         id                code new_col
>  1: C01182               13762       1
>  2: C00966               13762       1
>  3: C00130  13762, 13886,13850       1
>  4: d34567               55653       2
>  5: c34567               65247       3
>  6: C01142               13698       4
>  7: C00241               13698       4
>  8: C00232               13698       4
>  9: C01094               13880       5
> 10: C00979 13773, 13858, 13880       5
> 11: C00144        13773, 13880       5
> ```

What this does:

1. `setDT(df)` converts `df` to a `data.table`.
2. `d1 <- df[, .(code = unlist(tstrsplit(code, ',', type.convert = TRUE))), by = id]` converts `df` to long format where each `code` has a new row.
3. `d2 <- d1[, dcast(.SD, id ~ code, fun = length)][, -1]` creates a wide `data.table` with the `code`'s as columns and where for each `id` is indicated how many times a `code` is associated with it. With `[-1]` the `id` column is removed as we don't need it for the next step.
4. The last part can be split into several pieces:

   - `.(code = as.integer(names(d2)), val = colSums(as.matrix(d2)))` creates a long temporary `data.table` with for each `code` the number of times it occurs.
   - The temporary `data.table` from the previous step is joined with `d1` with `code` as join-key (`on = .(code)`) and the count is added to the corresponding `codes` by reference (`val := i.val`). After that for each `id` only the `code` with the highest number of counts (= `val`) is selected with the `[, .(code = code[which.max(val)]), by = id]`-part.
   - Finally this *most frequent code* is joined back to `df` by `id` (`on = .(id)`) and `new_col` is created by created making a *run-lenght-id* of `code` (`new_col := rleid(code)`).

---

A speed comparison on the larger dataset as specified by @minem:

```
n1 <- 10000
n2 <- 10000
set.seed(20)
ll <- lapply(1:n1, function(x) sample(1:n2, sample(1:5, 1)))
dfl <- data.table(id = 1:n1, code = sapply(ll, paste, collapse = ', '))
```

The timings:

> ```
> > system.time(getGroupsJaap(dfl))
>    user  system elapsed 
>   1.878   0.595   2.479 
>
> > system.time(getGroupsMinem(dfl))
>    user  system elapsed 
>   4.332   0.598   4.931
> ```

A further (though minor) improvement of my approach can be achieved by replacing `colSums` with `colSums2` from the `matrixStats`-package.

---

**Old answer:**

```
dfc <- lapply(strsplit(df$code, ','), type.convert)

m <- as.data.table(outer(unlist(dfc),
                         unlist(dfc),
                         '==')
                   )[, lapply(.SD, sum), rep(seq_along(dfc), lengths(dfc))
                     ][, rep := NULL][, t(.SD)]

dt <- data.table(id = rep(df$id, lengths(dfc)),
                 m)[, grp := .GRP, by = V1:V11
                    ][, rs := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = 2:12
                      ][, .(grp = grp[rs == max(rs)]), by = id
                        ][, unid := paste0('unique_id_', .GRP), by = grp][]

df[dt, on = .(id), new_col := unid][]
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind explaining  your code to a newbie like myself (especially with DT). I'm lost  starting from `, on = .(code), val := i.val][, .(code = code[which.max(val)]), by = id]
   , on = .(id)
   , new_col := rleid(i.code)]`

Comment: @cephalopod I will try to add an explanation later today

Comment: @cephalopod Sorry for the delay, but added an explanation now.